# Different text color for button and page text in FirebaseUI

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

I'm styling the FirebaseUI and would like to have different text colors for the buttons (like NEXT and SIGN IN) and rest of the text on the page. The only attribute that I've found that changes the text color is `android:textColor` but it changes the color for both.

[image: Sign in page]

Here is what it currently looks like when the color is set to red. Are there any attributes that apply to only the button text or the page text?

```
<style name="Theme.FirebaseUI" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
</style>
```

Comment: could u pls share the xml code?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal I edited the post and added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to separately style buttons. Added the following style:

```
<style name="FirebaseUI.Button" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">end</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Note the name has to be "FirebaseUI.Button" to work.